# Is lookbehind and lookaround concept avail in TCL regex engine?

Tags: regex, tcl, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

*Is lookbehind and lookaround concept avail in TCL regex engine?*

I came across [this page](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/regexp81.tml#part2_3), i didn't see any concept and example about lookbehind and lookaround, even when i execute sample program with lookbehind and lookaround concept where i am not getting **any match** as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes to lookahead, no to lookbehind, according to [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com), if you're using Tcl ARE (Advanced Regular Expressions).

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html and check the "Tcl ARE" dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and the given URL also seems like better and helpful thanks a lot..

Comment: And also according to the Tcl manual: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm