# backreferencing not working in tcl regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I am new to regular expressions and tcl and am facing very basic issue from a long time now.

I am given with the task to find all the characters in given word, whose immediate next character is not identical to this character. I have written following tcl snippet to achieve this:

```
set str "goooo";
set lst [regexp -all -inline {(\w)[^\1]} $str];
puts $lst
```

I am getting following error:

```
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: invalid escape \ sequence
    while executing
"regexp -all -inline {(\w)[^ \1]} $str"
```

Is there any other way to use backreferencing in tcl?

Comment: `[^\1]` means any char but a `\x01` char. Backreferences cannot be defined with bracket expressions. And `(?!\1)` is not supported in Tcl regex that does not support lookarounds.

Comment: Does `set lst [regexp -all -inline {\w} [regsub -all {(\w)\1+} $str ""]];` work for you?

Comment: Hi,
Is it only for tcl or all languages, that \1 cannot be put inside square brackets ?
Also what is \x01 ?

Comment: Backreferences cannot be used inside bracket expressions in all regex flavors.

Comment: set lst [regexp -all -inline {\w} [regsub -all {(\w)\1+} $str ""]]; => gets only first match 'g'

Comment: See https://ideone.com/N7V8Sh. `gooo` only has one letter `g` that has no other `g`s right after it. What do you expect to get for `sddgoooo`? For `sddgoooogd?`

Comment: also, can anyone please explain difference between lookahead and backreferencing ?

Comment: First, what are you expected outputs for the three strings above?

Comment: I wanted to get two matches: g and o(the last character also needs to be included)

Comment: Does `set lst [regexp -all -inline {\w} [regsub -all {(\w)\1+} $str {\1}]];` work as expected?

Comment: I am getting same result in the modified version

Comment: See https://ideone.com/N7V8Sh

Comment: Thanks, getting the answer right, but unable to get how you got this magical expression

Answer (score 1):

Backreferences cannot be used inside bracket expressions in any regex flavor. `[^\1]` matches any char but a `\x01` char. This happens so because bracket expressions are meant to use *exact literal characters or ranges of them*.

In your case, you can remove all chunks of repeated chars with `(\w)\1+` (while replacing with the same single char using the `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern) and then extract the word chars:

```
set lst [regexp -all -inline {\w} [regsub -all {(\w)\1+} $str {\1}]];
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/N7V8Sh):

```
set str "sddgoooo";
set lst [regexp -all -inline {\w} [regsub -all {(\w)\1+} $str {\1}]];
puts $lst
```

Output:

```
s d g o
```

Note that in other regex flavors, you could use a regex with a negative lookahead: `(\w)(?!\1)` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfeBcX/1)). The `(?!\1)` negative lookahead matches a location that is not immediately followed with Group 1 value. Unfortunately, Tcl regex flavor - although Tcl AREs generally [support lookaheads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21451699/3832970) - does not support lookaheads with backreference inside them.

Comment: It does support lookaheads, but doesn't support backreferences within them (because it uses a different DFA to match lookaheads, if I've understood the *extremely complicated* code in the RE engine correctly).

Comment: @DonalFellows I updated the end of the answer to reflect this.